# set automatically email address for WordPress users

Tags: users, user-registration

User registration on my site is done with a mobile number.
I want the email with the structure "{userid}@example.com" to be registered automatically after user registration.
How can I do this?
please guide me.

Comment: Usernames aren't considered secrets in WP, if you store the mobile numbers as user names then you'll be exposing personal data to the open web. This would be illegal in many countries and considered a major security breach. There are major security privacy and legal consequences to this, you should consult a lawyer.

Comment: e.g. anybody could go to `/wp-json/wp/v2/users` and see a list of users and their mobile numbers if you did this. At an absolute minimum you would need to store the mobile numbers as user meta then make up random strings for the username and emails. You could not use the mobile number of the user login value directly, or as the display name or nickname

Comment: @TomJNowell Right. 
But the mobile number is used only for user login and username.
How can I create random values for email and username that are set after user registration?

Comment: that's why I left a comment rather than writing an answer, user logins/names are not secrets in WP, if you use personally identifiable information then it will be exposed which is a data breach in many countries, EU nations in particular

Comment: @TomJNowell Ok! What is your solution for creating random emails and usernames after user registration?

Comment: Soheil, if all you care about is randomization, then just use this to generate a random string for each user name: `$randhash = substr( md5( microtime() ), rand( 0,26 ), 10 );`.  That will give you a 10 character randomized string. BUT, you'll also now have to build in a utility to check if it's a duplicate or not and if it is, run it again. This whole thing seems like a poor idea.  Why are you doing this? Maybe if we understand that a different suggestion can be put forth.